# setContentView in HelloAndroid can't find R

Tags: java, android

I just tried creating the default HelloAndroid project, and I am getting an error when calling setContentView & other methods referencing R (R cannot be resolved to a variable).

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

There is no R class in the gen folder. There is also no import android.R in MainActivity.java

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Some useful advicesin such a situation: Try importing R (your package one, not android's). Make sure your resource file names contain only allowed characters. Clean the project. Restart your IDE. And... PUSH THE BUTTON! ;)

Comment: I just deleted & recreated the project.  I noticed that the target & compile with API versions were not the same.  When I made both the latest version, that fixed it.